# SSL Certificate Verify Failed While Using SSO Snowflake Connection Object In write_panda method of Snowflake Python Connctor

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake Python connector in my python code and using write_pandas method to write dataframe to Snowflake table , Snowflake connection is one object that is used inside write_pandas method, while calling this method i am getting error as SSL Certificate Verify Failed While Using SSO Snowflake Connection Object. Any idea what is reason for this error

Comment: Can you try to connect through Snowsql using the same SSO mechanism and see if the error is seen. If yes, use the following command to get more details / logs :

snowsql -a <account> -u <user name> --authenticator <type> -o log_level=debug -o log_path=<path>/ssodebug.log

Comment: Hi @Srinath Menon, I am able to connect to Snowflake using Web UI in SSO mode, accessing SNowflake using Snowsql is restricted in my environment.

Comment: Do you have a proxy in between? If yes, you might need to whitelist the URL returned by [SYSTEM$WHITELIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_whitelist.html)

Comment: Connecting from web mode would not give the right set of data / debug to figure out the root cause hence I suggested snowsql because that would show the exact reason for error, if it does not connect. Other than that do you have proxy in this setup? If yes, then test with NO_PROXY as mentioned here : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-a-proxy-server

Comment: @Sergiu , thanks for reply ; I am able to make SSO Connection to my Snowflake using Snowflake Python Connector using SSO external browser method; so still do you think the hostnames from SYSTEM$WHITELIST  should be added to firewall.

Comment: Yes, if you have a firewall or proxy that insects/filters those URLs from SYSTEM$WHITELIST. The error "SSL Certificate Verify Failed" makes me think that the [OCSP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ocsp.html) check fails or you have an SSL proxy that manipulates the SSL certificate (replaces the certificate with its own certificate).